# Api Platform + Symfony define differents groups for get all and get single

Tags: symfony, serialization, get, api-platform.com

I have an object control with a lot of properties encapsuled. When i make a GET request /controls/{id} to get just one control i want more properties than GET request /controls who return me all my controls.

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     formats={"json"},
 *     forceEager=false,
 *     itemOperations={
 *      "get"={
 *          "normalizationContext"={
 *              "groups"={"control:read"}
 *          }
 *      }
 *     },
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"fullcontrol:read"}, "enable_max_depth"=true})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ControlRepository::class)
 */
class Control
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"control:read"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Appointment::class, mappedBy="control", orphanRemoval=true)
     * @Groups({"control:read"})
     */
    private $appointments;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=ObjectEntity::class, mappedBy="control", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @Groups({"fullcontrol:read"})
     */
    private $objectEntity;
```

Here my @ApiRessource header to do that. In the doc they explains the most specific normalizationContext will be used but it always use the control:read group and never the fullcontrol:read group

Anyone know how to make it working ?

Comment: Could you add a subset of your properties with the groups annotation please

Comment: Sure ! I added sample of my properties next to the annotations

Comment: In your example `fullcontrol:read` is defined as the default serialization group, which means it will be added to every operation on your resources. On the other side, `control:read` group is only on the GET operation. So, you should add this serialization group to the properties you want to be described

Comment: Yes that was the goal ^^ I find the problem : it's just syntaxe : normalization_context into the itemOperation and normalizationContext as global ^^